# Javascript content manipulation

Tags: javascript

For example I've got the got a random HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>javascript</h1>

<p>bla bla</p>

<script src="sample1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

With its sample1.js code:

```
var a = 1234;
var b = 0.2;

console.log("this a simple script");
console.log(a * b);
```

I would like to know if is there any possibility to find all integers and floats from sample1.js and after executed to re-execute the same content but with any other random generated int or float values.

To sum up, I would sample1.html file to refresh but with sample1.js to contain any other random values for a and b

Comment: Do you want a button on the page to reload sample1.js, or do you just need to create random numbers? I would like to know what your goal is

Comment: Umm...I really don't understand your question. What random variables? Do you want `var a` and `var b` to have random variables assigned?

Comment: This sounds a lot like some homework assignment.  Try first searching in google for "random number javascript" and go from there.

Comment: You can statically analyze the code and replace all instances of numbers with different numbers. E.g. with recast: https://github.com/benjamn/recast

Answer (score 0):

After execution I would the page to be automatically reloaded but all the integers and floats in the page to be randomized with other values.

I know I can statically analyze the code. Image I have a very long functionality test script which tests various functions. I would like to add a custom function which parses all integers and floats in my page and then reload the page automatically with messed up values for my variables.